# ActiveMQ, Broker Url: how to run on port number other than default 61616

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I am trying to run on the port number 5000, tcp://localhost:5000

it shows the following error

> WARNING: Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination
> 'queue://jmsExample' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect
> to broker URL: tcp://localhost:5000. Reason:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Any Help please

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What does your config file look like etc.

Comment: The problem can be an existing process using the port, or a local firewall blocking access to the port. You need to first confirm that the port is listening on the server side, and that it responds to client-side connections.

Answer (score 0):

The port 5000 is already in use by another process or service

Comment: i tried with multiple port numbers like 23689, 64590..
it gives the same error